# Which deity is to be invoked (or appeased) first in a Vedic ritual?

Tags: worship, vedic-gods, vedic-rituals

In today's time most of the worship/rituals that are done are done based on the injunctions of the Tantras. Sometimes the Puranic methods are also followed ( for e.g. Durga Puja in Bengal). Sometimes a mixture of methods.

And, in this style of worship, Lord Ganesha usually is invoked/appeased first. That is why he is called "Prathama Pujya".

But in a Vedic fire ritual, is there a deity which is to be invoked/appeased first? Of course Agni is to invoked first otherwise the ritual will not even start.

But apart from him, is there a rule that a particular deity must receive the first Havi (oblation)? Like say Brahmanaspati, Varuna or any other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Gobhila Grihya Sutra: 1.4.4](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe30/sbe30007.htm), first oblation is sacred to Prajapati.

> 1. 1 He then should silently offer the Balis.
> 2. Let him speak only what refers to the due preparation of the food. With guests he may converse, if he likes.
> 3. He then should take some portion of food which is fit for sacrifice, should pour over it some liquid fit for sacrifice (such as ghee, milk, or curds), and should sacrifice it silently in the fire with his hand.
> 4. **The first oblation is sacred to Pragâpati**, the second to (Agni) Svishtakrit.

Comment: That's great find I guessed it has to be Prajapati ..

Comment: Is this Lord Prajapati same or diffearent from Lord Brahma?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda Prajapati should be Lord Brahma here.